# Seperate Text and Image from String and wrap Text in <p> tag php

Tags: php

**input**

```
$str = '<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/ipad-air-hands-on-angle.jpg"> Apple's plan to launch the iPad Air with cellular data support for T-Mobile was apparently just the start of a larger strategy. US Cellular has announced that it will offer the featherweight tablet on November 8th, while regional carriers like Bluegrass Cellular, C Spire and GCI say that they'll ...'

$str2 = '<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/ipad-air-hands-on-angle.jpg">Apple's plan to launch the iPad Air with cellular data support for T-Mobile was apparently just the start of a larger strategy. US Cellular has announced that it will offer the featherweight tablet on November 8th, while regional carriers like Bluegrass Cellular, C Spire and GCI say that they'll ...'
```

**output i need**

```
<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/ipad-air-hands-on-angle.jpg">
<p>Apple's plan to launch the iPad Air with cellular data support for T-Mobile was apparently just the start of a larger strategy. US Cellular has announced that it will offer the featherweight tablet on November 8th, while regional carriers like Bluegrass Cellular, C Spire and GCI say that they'll ...</p>
```

How would I go about getting the output I need from the above 2 strings? I have tried the following but this doesn't seem all that great.

```
            $item_content = str_replace('> ', '> <p>', $item_content); 
            $item_content = str_replace('>', '> <p>', $item_content);
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DOMDocument`:

```
$str = '<img ... /> text ...';

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHtml($str);

$img_tag = $html->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->C14N();
$text = trim($html->textContent);
```

You can then just output that in any manner you like:

```
echo "{$img_tag}\n<p>{$text}</p>";
```

Comment: @Beardy Check if `$html->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)` returns `NULL` or not. With that you should be able to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression. It will be:

```
$str = '<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/ipad-air-hands-on-angle.jpg"> Apple\'s plan to launch the iPad Air with cellular data support for T-Mobile was apparently just the start of a larger strategy. US Cellular has announced that it will offer the featherweight tablet on November 8th, while regional carriers like Bluegrass Cellular, C Spire and GCI say that they\'ll ...';

if(preg_match('/^(<img[\S\s]+?>)([\S\s]*)$/i', $str, $matches)) {
    $img = $matches[1];
    $text = trim($matches[2]);
    echo "$img\n<p>$text</p>";      
}
```